# IDE insert white space and the browser read them as char how to get rid of it? i'm using VSCode

Tags: html, css

When I'm trying to make navbar there was a problem with space which I don't know from where it came!

I set the margin to 0 and the padding nothing happened
also box-sizing to border-box no luck !

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xreeX.png): [image]

```
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: 1px #e7e7e7 solid;
    color: #777;
}

.logo,
.navbar {
    display: inline;
}

.logo {
    padding: 20px;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `*::after: content: ""` ?? Also, show the real html of the nav plz.

Comment: @wazz not working :\

Comment: One more wild guess, wondering what happens if you remove line breaks between `li`s --  `<li>content</li><li>content</li><li>content</li>`.

Comment: @wazz wth after removing the breaks and the space between the tags, the #text thing gone
any explanation for what is happening??

Comment: Not really, sorry. I figured it had to do with a `setting/option` somewhere that interprets line breaks *not* as empty but as a character to be included. Which IED are you using? Someone else jump in here if you know of a setting for this.

Comment: @wazz this is what I thought some thing with the IED, I'm using vscode

Comment: You might not have to remove the line breaks if you're sure all the white-space is gone between the line breaks. There's a tool in `Web Essentials by Mads Kristensen` that removes extra white space. It might help. I haven't checked if it works in `VS Code`.

Comment: @wazz No, it doesn't work in VS Code, but I will try to find a solution for that, thanks for leading me for the right path where to search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this would solve it for you!

```
.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since these elements have a "native" spacing between them, you can give your `nav-item` class a negative margin, like so:

```
.nav-item {
  margin: -7px;
}
```

And since doing this will probably affect the parent element `<nav>`, you can set the parent element's height manually, so it keeps the element at the height (or size) you want:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: 1px #e7e7e7 solid;
    color: #777;
    height: 55px; /*This property should set the height to your nav element*/
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think it's something with the IDE, not the stylesheet itself, maybe your solution will work, but I'm looking for a better and future solution

Answer (score 0):

Set the width the body of the html like this body {width : 100vw} this will set it to 100 view width of your browser and remove the unexpected spaces. I hope this helps

Comment: I think it's something with the IDE, not the stylesheet itself, maybe your solution will work, but I'm looking for a better and future solution

Answer (score 0):

there is **native** space between these elements.

anyway u should do like this

```
.navbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    content :""
}
```

Comment: Please make sure the answer given works